# Resizing Input boxes and maintaining alignment

Tags: html, css, html-input

I am trying to resize my zip code input box to be half the size of the container. In the mobile version of my site it works. But if I try to change it in my media query at 768 px to be 50vw it knocks out the alignment with the other input boxes. I can kind of half ass make it look decent by adding some left margin to the zip input box but how would I take the code that I currently have here and have everything scale with my inputs all lining up but have the ZIP input box be only half as big as the others?? Thanks in advance! Below is a link to my code!

https://github.com/Freedomcoding101/online-registration-project.git

I tried to change the

```
  li:last-child {
        max-width: 50vw;
    }
```

and I can see that it does in fact make it 50 percent of the size but this knocks the input out of alignment with the others. How can I maintain the equal sizing of the labels and have the input box be half the size of the other?

I also tried to target the #zip-code and make it 50vw and also a pixel size but it wasnt working either..

Comment: with max-width: 50vw you don't get the half of the parent, you get 50% of the visible viewport. you have to set a width to the parent and after that you can set the child's width to the half. But without more code it is hard to help, so please show more code

Answer (score 0):

You are using flexbox, and flex items get auto-sized based on their content.

You've set width: 100px to your labels. Fix min-width for your labels, too:

```
label {
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Remove your max-width: 50% from the last li, either with this style rule or just remove your rule that sets max-width 50%:

```
li:last-child {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}
```

Set .c1 that is direct child of last li sized to 100% of its li parent minus label width (100px) and margins (10 and 20px) — this way, the 50% in the next rule will be precisely half of other inputs, not of the total width of label + input and margins

```
li:last-child > .c1 {
    max-width: calc(100% - 100px - 20px - 10px);
}
```

Now set width of input.c1 to 50% of its container:

```
li:last-child .c1 input.c1 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Also: see the gap property ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)) — with it, you can make gaps between flex items without margins or paddings.